# Git still tracks files which i had added in .gitignore

Tags: android, git

I am using android studio. While commiting my changes, one file gets modified automatically

```
    modified:   .idea/misc.xml
```

I don't want to add this file to my commit(Because it is autogenerated). I had added this to gitignore. But it still tracks. Is there any way to remove this file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Comment: @1615903 But do we know for certain that this file was previously tracked?  Perhaps one of his coworkers accidentally committed the file, and now everyone is getting hosed.

Comment: Use `git rm --cached .idea/misc.xml`, then push.  This should remove it from the repo, it it's actually there.

Comment: Yes, we know that it was tracked, because the status message says "modified" instead of "new"

Comment: I am getting error like `fatal: pathspec '.idea/misc.xml' did not match any files` @1615903 @Tim

Comment: Ok, what exactly is the output of `git status` and what exactly is the contents of your `.gitignore` file?